# How is creating a negative delay possible in this case?

Tags: digital-logic, pulse

I want to create a negative phase shift (delay) from an original clock source:

[image]

Source will start, but at some point Vout will lead Vsource as follows:

[image]

How can that be possible?

Comment: A phase-locked loop?

Comment: Actually I noticed initial pulses are also important. So even the first output pulse should be delayed negative. Is that possible with PLL?

Comment: That's not possible period, you're asking to violate causality.

Comment: How many pulses are enough at initially? I can only sacrifice the first one

Comment: It depends on what assumptions you can make about the pulse. Do you know for certain what its period will be?

Comment: 10% duty 20kHz freq

Comment: If you know for a fact that it will *always* be that same frequency, then only one pulse is required to initiate it. You'll need to just operate a second synchronized pulse generator at a fixed delay from the reference.

Comment: If you control both the original source and the 'pulse anticipator circuit', you can achieve that effect.

Comment: If the clock pulses are fixed width and frequency you can delay by 360-Lead degrees, after the first cycles it will be indistinguishable from a negative delay.

Comment: @Neil_UK I dont and cannot control the original source

Answer (score 7):

If you want the Vout pulse to start t_delay before Vsource, based on Vsource and nothing else, then it is impossible (it would violate causality).

If Vource is regular (period T), and you are OK to loose the first pulse on Vout, then you can just add a positive delay of T-t_delay to generate Vout from Vsource.

Another solution, specialy if t_delay needs to be more accurate than the period, would be to reverse the problem : but your clock generator on Vout, and add the positive delay t_delay to generate Vsource